# Call Forms from Two C# projects in a third Project

Tags: c#, projects-and-solutions

This is the first time I start with StackOverflow... 
I think my question is a silly question!! 
I need to call the forms and classes from two C# projects in a third project

I follow these steps:

1. From Solution Explorer in a third project, I have clicked the Add Reference
2. I click the Project Tab
3. I didn't find any add browsing to add these two projects. see the image

Comment: Mmmm ... no image brodah :)

Comment: Are you sure.. other two projects are part of same solution?

Comment: I just create two  projects individually, Now, I need to call their forms from the third one to make some attractable implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Create your multiple project in a single solution. then add project1 and project2 in your project3 reference using >> Add Reference >> Projects >> Solution.

here's how: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f3st0d45.aspx

Comment: Please see my image below, there is no tab to add these two projects from project tab

Answer (score 1):

Your Projects should be under same solution.
If in case you are building two projects differently not under same solution follow these steps

1.Create a winform project let say "Project1" go to project settings change the output type to class library and build it.

2.Create another winform project lets say "Project2" go to project setting change the output type to class library and build it

3.Create third project from where you want to call it. Go to Add reference. Browse for folders as below

- debug folder of project1 select project1.dll and add reference.
- debug folder of project2 select project2.dll and add reference.

  4.Now create objects of Forms and call.

Comment: Excuse me coz i can't vote for your answer. I got only 11 reputation

Answer (score 0):

Alright. Visual Studio offers you the ability to add references you just created yourself. Those references could be (dynamic-link-)libraries `DLL` or executables `EXE`. So go ahead and create a project and add a new `Form`. This custom `Form` needs to be `public` so the other project is able to extract the code.

Now you are able to add and use a reference. Just be sure to include the namespace, if it doesn't match the one, in which you're going to use it.

The thing is called [Project-to-project Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ez524kew%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)